# Show that a linear operator P is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

inner product (A|B) = tr(A B^t)

linear operator A(X) = X^t

Is P skew or self adjoint?
self = P = P*
neg is skew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider a family $E_{i,j}$ basis of $M(2,\Bbb R)$ such as $E_{i,j}^t = E_{j,i}$.
In such a basis the matrix of $A$ is symetrical.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $\langle A(X),Y \rangle = trace(X^tY^t)=trace(YX)^t$ while

$\langle X,A(Y) \rangle= trace(XY)$. Are these two equal?

Also, $A^2(X)=A(X^t)=(X^t)^{t}=X$. So, $A$ is a projection. When is a projection orthogonal projection?